# Corrupt form data: premature ending on Alcatel OT900A

Tags: java, forms, servlets, stripes, alcatel-ot

I am trying to submit a form using an Alcatel OT900A but I am getting this error

ava.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending 
at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:205) 
at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.(MultipartRequest.java:222) 
at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.(MultipartRequest.java:173) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.multipart.CosMultipartWrapper.build(CosMultipartWrapper.java:63) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.multipart.DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.wrap(DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.java:125) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesRequestWrapper.constructMultipartWrapper(StripesRequestWrapper.java:109) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesRequestWrapper.(StripesRequestWrapper.java:95) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.wrapRequest(StripesFilter.java:202) 
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:171) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188) 
at com.colibria.imps.clients.xhtml.filter.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:39) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:113) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Do you have any idea what is this error? Something wrong in the server or is it the device? I've tried testing this on other devices and it is working. It's only in Alcatel OT900A that I get this error.

My form looks like this (ofcourse I omitted some of the codes):

```
<stripes:form action="Some_Action_Bean" method="post">
   <stripes:text name="somemessage" class="someclass"/>
   <stripes:file name="someFile" class="someClass"/>
</stripes:form>
```

there were some text entered in "somemessage" field but no file was chosen so basically "someFile" is null. I just have a checking in the backend if the value of the file is null.

I was thinking if the error occurred because no enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form, or maybe the stripes framework has an error itself or maybe the device doesn't support file sending.

Comment: I found out that the device doesn't support file upload.

Answer (score 0):

File uploaded is not proper, `errror parsing multipart data...`
This is not about just form, but the file which has been uploaded along with request is corrupt or not complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think the cause of this error is because my form doesn't have enctype="multipart/form-data"? I'm also having a hard time testing this because I don't have the device right now. Cheers.

Comment: should be, content type shold be multipart/form-data

Comment: I've thought of that also. I added some details in my question. It would really help if you could give me your additional thoughts based on the additional details. Thanks